Installing KOReader on openSUSE Tumbleweed without using Flatpak
I'm trying to install the KOReader e-book reader application on my openSUSE Tumbleweed system, but I don't want to use the Flatpak version. Is there a way to install KOReader from native packages or by building it from source on openSUSE Tumbleweed?
I've tried searching the official openSUSE repositories, but I couldn't find KOReader listed. I'm open to either using a third-party repository or building KOReader from source if there are instructions available.
My main requirement is to avoid using Flatpak, as I prefer to use native packages when possible. Can someone please guide me on how to get KOReader installed on openSUSE Tumbleweed without using Flatpak?
Please let me know if you need any other details regarding my system or the specific version of KOReader I'm trying to install.

there are 2 methods for installing koreader on opensuse
option 1) using the appimage, they have a appimage available for installation
option 2) converting the .deb to rpm
first download the .deb package
then install alien
then alien -r package.deb
lastly rpm -Uvh rpm_package
source

Thanks a lot - @cinemassacres !

which way is better?

@Dr.P appimage is easier in that you don't have to see if converting a deb to rpm will work

Thanks! @killertofus

you're welcome @Dr.P
